# List down all the tables in Snowflake Schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a requirement to list down all the tables created under snowflake schema.
I tried using "Show Tables" and "Information_Schema.Tables", but these only list the tables accessible to me. I need to be able to see the entire list of tables irrespective of the access.

Is there a way I can do it other than Admin access?

Comment: You can not list tables that you do not have access to.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can list all the tables for which you have access privileges - which role(s) that is depends on how you've set up your account

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see any information, even the names, of tables that you do not have access to. This is fundamental to Snowflake's role-based access. Your user must be assigned a role that has the necessary access.